# What's the correspondence between Feynman diagrams and field configurations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, perturbation-theory, interactions

If I understand correctly, a Feynman diagram represents a finite set of "interactions", such as the exchange of a photon between two electrons.  You can think of it as a graph in which the vertices are the interactions.  Otherwise, each particle propagates freely from one vertex to the next (such that the inter-vertex propagator for an electron, for example, comes from the free Dirac equation).

Then you integrate over the coordinates where these interactions can happen.  For example, in the simple case of a single photon exchange, you'd integrate over the spacetime location $\mathbf{x_1}$ where the first electron could be when it emits the photon, as well as the position $\mathbf{x_2}$ where the second electron could receive it -- under the constraint that $\mathbf{x_1}$ and $\mathbf{x_2}$ are null-separated, since we're talking about a photon.

Finally, you add up the integrals corresponding to every possible interaction graph, to get a net amplitude for each final state.  This is what I (think I) understood from reading Feynman's 1949 paper, [Space-Time Approach to QED](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/3523/1/FEYpr49c.pdf).

But then, I've also read that, in general, the path integral approach to QFT says to integrate over all possible *field configurations*.  Which doesn't seem to me to be quite the same thing.  The former is an integral over graphs with a discrete set of vertices, which is surely a smaller space than the set of all configurations, each of which has an independent value at every point in infinite spacetime.

So, is there some constraint on the actual allowable field configurations that renders these two sets equivalent?  If so, what manner of constraint?  Or is it rather that the number of vertices in the diagram can be arbitrarily large, so that it can approach any continuous field configuration in the limit?  In that case, I guess the simpler Feynman diagrams would actually be more like delta-functions when construed as field configurations.  Yet we know that these contribute much more to the overall amplitude, so could we conclude that nature tends to behave more like delta-functions than delocalized clouds?

Comment: Some small comments: 1) Both are approaches to computing multiparticle scattering amplitudes $<in | out>$, with $|in>$ and $|out>$ products of 1-particle states. They are perturbatively the equivalent.

Comment: 2) In the original Feynman approach you have to sum over all worldgraphs. Suppose you have a 1-1 scattering. Then you have topological sectors with 1 loop, 2 loops, 3 loops etc. Clearly as we approach many particles in the interaction, they densely fill out spacetime, which is caught very well by representing the excitations as a field configuration instead. The divergence of this perturbative series is somehow caught in the ill-defined nature of the path integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Feynman diagram and a field configuration is not the same thing. The field configurations are the integration field variables over which the path integral is evaluated. However, the path integral for each specific process can be used to generate all the Feynman diagrams to all orders for that process. It is done by adding source terms for the different fields to the action and then pull out the part with the interaction terms using functional derivatives.

So, what does a field configuration have to do with what the Feynman diagram represents? It is always dangerous and potentially misleading to try and give physical meaning to part of a mathematical process that computes a physical result. In this case, one has the infinite sum of Feynman diagrams on one hand in which fields interact via the vertices, and on the other hand one has the functional integration of the process as represented by the action for a given process over all field configurations.

Perhaps a way to see this is that the functional integral "tests" each field configuration by applying it to the action under the constraints of the input and output fields to obtain a weight in the form of a probability amplitude for that field configuration. All the probability amplitudes for the field configurations are then added by the integral.

In terms of the Feynman diagrams, these field configurations are represented by the basis functions (plane waves) in terms of which the propagators are computed. If you want to think in terms of the field configurations, then they are again "tested" by applying them to the structure of interactions as represented by the diagram, to obtain probability amplitudes. In this case, the interactions are integrated over all positions leading to different probability amplitudes for each field configuration. So, in effect the sum over Feynman diagrams adds all the probability amplitudes for all the field configurations and all possible positions of the interactions in all the Feynman diagrams.

It sounds like a rather complicated business if you try to think of it like this, but it is all included in the whole calculation process.

Comment: Okay, let me see if I have it straight: although they are somewhat different approaches/decompositions, still there *is* a one-to-one mapping.  And in particular, given a Feynman diagram, we can construct the corresponding field configuration by replacing the free propagation intervals ("edges" of the graph) with plane waves (made of spinors for fermions or vectors for bosons?). How's that?  Even then, it's not clear to me how you would sew two "plane wave segments" together, like when the electron suddenly changes direction at the vertex.

Comment: Was there an original paper where this was initially laid out?

Comment: This understanding is the stuff of text books now. However, they don't necessarily do the comparison as posed in your question. I don't know of any papers that explain it in this way either.

Comment: The plane wave "segments" are "sown together" by the vertex rule, which represents a point interaction. Remember, the plane waves combine to form the propagators, which are like Green functions spreading out from previous interaction points. So the change in direction of a particle is more a change in the locations of the interaction points.

Comment: So is the field configuration just a superposition of one Green's function from each vertex (propagating only forward in time, I suppose)?  And could that apply to the vector gauge field as well?  But then, doesn't the field configuration at the final time have to be an eigenstate of the multi-particle observable?-- for example, if you're measuring position, doesn't it have to basically be a sum of a couple of delta functions?  And I don't see how Green's functions would do that.  Because a given configuration corresponds to a particular "history", so it has to have a well-defined final state.

Comment: It is far more complicated that such a simple one to one relationship would allow. You have two completely different superpositions on the two side, which makes it very difficult to relate them. Although you have Green functions, you still have to integrate them over all positions for the interactions, smearing them out. The result then needs to be compared not to one single field configuration, but to a superposition of such field configurations.